# How-to force a Jasmine test response to go through the rxjs catch

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I have a service as follows:

```
createProdCategory( prodcategory: IProdCategory ) {
    console.log(prodcategory);
    return this.http.post( this.url, prodcategory )
        .map( ( response: Response ) => response.json( ) )
        .catch( this.handleError );
}
...
handleError( error: any ) {
    console.error( error );
    return Observable.throw( error.json( ).error || 'Service error' );
}
```

I would like to test the path through the ***handleError*** function, by way of the RXJS ***catch***.  My spec is as follows:

```
 it( 'should handle an error on create...', async(() => {
  let mockData: ProdCategory = mockDatum[ 2 ];
  backend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
    let response: Response = new Response(
      new ResponseOptions( { body: JSON.stringify( { error: `${errMsg}` } ), status: 404, statusText: `${errMsg}` } ));
    connection.mockRespond( response );
  });
  expect( 
      sut.createProdCategory( mockData ).subscribe((resp) => {
          fail( 'handleError: expected error...' );
      } )
    ).toThrowError( errMsg );
}));
```

Unfortunately, the ***catch*** is not invoked and the error message is not thrown.  How-to force the response to go through the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simulate an error in response.

So instead of

```
  connection.mockRespond( response );
```

use

```
  connection.mockError(response);
```

and after that in subscribe you have to handle the error case:

```
sut.createProdCategory( mockData ).subscribe(
    () => {},
    error => {
       expect(error)......
     }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Julia, it is now going through the ***handleError***.  I have some work to do on the expect.

Comment: The test now looks like the following:
sut.createProdCategory( mockData ).subscribe((resp) => { ... },
 ( error ) => { expect( error ).toEqual( errMsg ); }